# Check When New Element Is Created

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `div.scrollContainer` where I insert a bunch of items. When the page loads, I run mCustomScrollbar jQuery plugin which will take the items inside `div.scrollContainer` and wrap its own classes/css/js around it to create the custom scroll bar.

When the page loads, I go through my own library which outputs some more items for me to inject into the scroll bar. I am currently targeting/appending them to the custom classes mCustomScrollbar creates. The problem, however, is that sometimes my library outputs the items before mCustomScrollbar has created its classes. As a result, the items from the library can never be placed inside the correct element because it doesn't exist.

I have thought about appending the items from the library to `div.scrollContainer`, but then I run into the issue of what if mCustomScrollbar has created its classes before the items are appended.

All in all, I am wondering if there is a way to detect when a new element is created in the DOM. I have looked into this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780937/1179449) where it was suggested to use the livequery plugin. I'm wondering if there is a solution that does not require an additional plugin.

Comment: Can you insert those later items before calling `mCustomScrollbar` or you need those mCustomScrollbar's classes to append them? If you can insert them first you can try calling `$("div.scrollContainer").mCustomScrollbar();` right after your items are inserted (using the `.append` callback, for example).

Comment: @scumah That works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Sure @icu222much, there you go, I'm glad it helped. And btw, I mentioned it in my previous comment, but there's no such thing as the .append callback :/ In fact, there's no need for one. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.mCustomScrollbar()` after inserting the last items, so you are positively sure that the items are really inserted:

```
$(".your-container").append($(".your-items"));
$("div.scrollContainer").mCustomScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the updateOnContentResize: true setting and it will check every few milliseconds for new content.
When you launch the plugin, also add these among your other settings:
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar({
advanced:{
    updateOnContentResize: true
}
});

However! Personally I am against useless DOM traversing every few milliseconds, I recommend you use its native update method.
Find a way to know when you add more content to your scrollbar markup and just run this whenever needed:
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("update");

P.S. read its documentation, quite many and useful settings/methods.

Hope this helps :)