# Get notification when DOM-Element is added

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect when a new element has been added to the document in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780822/how-can-i-detect-when-a-new-element-has-been-added-to-the-document-in-jquery)

I have a list of comments in a normal ul element. When loading the page I use something like (the system is based on templates)

```
<li id="someId">Some Content</li>
<script>doStuffWithLi('someId');</script>
```

So if the page is loaded and there are some li's, each one based on the template, there is this block for each li.

Now people can post a new comment and the template and the content is loaded into the page again - but this time the script is not executed. I guess js that is loaded after document ready in general is not executed, ones the document is loaded?

Unfortunately there is no jQuery function like `$('li').live('ready', function() {});`.
I tried it with the livequery plugin like `$('li').livequery(function() {//DO STUFF});` - But this didnt work as well. I cannot simply add a call to the creation of the element, because i can not influence the function adding the comment.

Is it possible to call a function as another li is added?

Comment: 1) Why don't you hook into the function that adds the li in the first place? 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: @Alexander Feder 'I cannot simply add a call to the creation of the element, because i can not influence the function adding the comment.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the event `DOMSubtreeModified`. Assign this event to the parent of your lis and check if the event gets fired if there is a new li. In this case you assign a new handler to that li.

```
$("#li_parent").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("possibly a li has been inserted");
    // do your magic here
});
```

Comment: not for IE7 + 8 but still ok. Works quite good :) Thank you