# event Listener for checking if a new child node is added to target Node

Tags: javascript

Is there any kind of event listener in javascript which checks if any new child node is added to the target node?
If not, is there any way to keep track of a particular node to check if a new child Node is added to it

To Make my question more comprehensive I'll use a small example,
So consider,

```
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
```

So in the above context can we add an eventListener to **ul** Node to check if a new **li**  node is added to it(dynamically via js) ?

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I could not understand the callback() {Callback function to execute when mutations are observed} of MutationObserver(), I mean the parameter of the callback is a bit confusing the function body  too is confusing could you please explain it to me

Comment: The [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271114/5625547) gives an example using `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Yeah, I read the answer and could understand it partiallly. I'll read some more blogs and would understand it maybe. Thanks for the help @0stone0